# Convergence radius for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-x)^{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, maple

I have the following multiple choice question.

> What is the convergence radius, $\rho$ for $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-x)^{n-1} $$
>
> 1. $\rho=0$
> 2. $\rho = 1$
> 3. $\rho = -1$
> 4. $\rho = 2$
> 5. The sequence doesn't have a convergence radius at all.

**My attempt**

Call $a_n=n(-x)^{n-1}$. We use the "ratio test".
$$\Big| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \Big| = \Big| \frac{(n+1) \cdot (-x)^n}{n(-x)^{n-1}} \Big|=\Big| \frac{x(n+1)}{n} \Big|$$

We see that $\Big| \frac{x(n+1)}{n} \Big| \rightarrow |x| \: \: \text{for} \: \: n\rightarrow \infty$.

For $x$ to be convergent, we must have $|x|<1$, which finally means that
$$-1<x<1 $$
which I assume means that the sequence has a convergence radius of $1$.

However, using Maple to double check, I find that the sequence actually converges when $x>-1$, and there is no upper bound on it. Am I doing something wrong?

**Checking with Maple**

[image]

Comment: The radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, Kavi. Can you perhaps explain why I'm getting these results in Maple? As I understand it, it is only the values inside the convergence radius that makes the sequence converge? Am I correct? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: The series is convergent if and only if $-1<x<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about Maple. Using the latest version (Maple 2020) one can obtain the following piecewise result, where `x` is taken as a parameter.

```
restart;

sum(n*(-x)^(n-1),n=1..infinity,parametric);

           /                     1     
           |      0            - - = 0 
           |                     x     
           |                           
           |      1                    
           |  ---------        |x| < 1 
           |          2                
          <   (-x - 1)                 
           |                           
           |   infinity                
           | - ---------       1 <= -x 
           |   signum(x)               
           |                           
           |  undefined       otherwise
           \
```

As for the results you found strange, for `x>=1`, notice that the Description in the Maple Help page for [numeric summation](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=evalf/Sum) mentions the concept of a "formal" summation.

If you force that off by supplying the `formal=false` option then result would be, for example,

```
restart;

evalf(Sum(n*(-1)^(n-1),n=1..infinity,formal=false));

           Float(undefined)

evalf(Sum(n*(-2)^(n-1),n=1..infinity,formal=false));

           Float(undefined)
```

You unfortunately wrapped lowercase `sum` in a call to `evalf`. The inner call to `sum` will return with the `formal` option stripped off, hence the undesired result.

```
restart;

sum(n*(-1)^(n-1),n=1..infinity,formal=false);

                infinity             
                 -----               
                  \                  
                   )          (n - 1)
                  /     n (-1)       
                 -----               
                 n = 1               

lprint(%);

       sum(n*(-1)^(n-1),n = 1 .. infinity)

evalf(%);

               0.2500000000
```

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that radius of convergence is 1 (answer choice 2). However the ratio test is inconclusive if the series will converge when $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1$. To determine this you need you need to check the end points -1 and 1. In this case, the series diverges at both end points $x=-1$ and $x=1$ so the interval of convergence is $(-1, 1)$.